# The sequence $G(n,k)=G(n-2,k)+G(n,k-2)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences

Background: The binomial coefficients $C(n,k)$ satisfy the recurrence
$C(n,k)=C(n-1,k)+C(n-1,k-1)$ and some terminating conditions, for
more information check [here](http://penguin.ewu.edu/~trolfe/BinomialCoeff/).

$C(n,k)$ doesn't appear to be efficiently computable via the recurrence
even with caching, but it can be computed in time $O(n)$ via the
factorial formula.

For natural $n,k$, define $G(n,k)=G(n-2,k)+G(n,k-2)$ if $n,k>2$,
otherwise the terminating conditions are $G(n,k)=n+k$.
If necessary, change the terminating conditions for the questions below.

> Q1 What is the time complexity of computing $G(n,k)$?
>   Is it $O(n)$ (we have $G(n,k)=G(k,n)$).
>
> Q2 How is $G(n,n)$ growing? Is it $c^n$ for some constant $c$?
>
> Q3 Is there combinatorial interpretation of $G(n,k$), is it counting
>   something?

Comment: Note that $G(2n,2k),G(2n+1,2k),G(2n,2k+1),G(2n+1,2k+1)$ satisfy the same recurrence as $C(n,k)$ so should be expressible as their linear combinations. I don't have a notebook on me though so I can't give you the formulas.

Answer (score 6):

The sequence $G(2n,2k)$ is $T(n,k)/2$, where $T(n,k)$ is [A051601](http://oeis.org/A051601). For $G(2n,2k+1)$ boundary conditions $1,3,5,7,\ldots$ can be replaced by $0,2,4,6$ (minus one Pascal triangle). It gives $G(2n,2k)$ again. Almost the same for $G(2n+1,2k+1)$ (minus two Pascal triangles).

Comment: Thank you. Do you require $k \le n$?

Comment: @joro No, everything is like in Pascal triangle $(n,k \ge 0).$

Comment: @joro Sorry, probably it was not clear. In this case Pascal triangle fills the first coordinate quarter: $C(n,0)=C(0,k)=1,$ $C(n,k)=C(n-1,k)+C(n,k-1).$

Comment: Is the following generalization solvable:  for natural A,B define $G(n,k)=G(n-A,k)+G(n,k-B)$?

Comment: @joro Yes, because in this case the answer is the sum of 2 trangles. First one has 0, 0, 0, ... and 0, A, 2A, 3A,...  on it's sides, second one has 0, B, 2B,... and 0, 0, 0,... respectively. In both cases you'll get Pascal triangle multiplied by A or by B and shifted. For n and k not divisable by A and B one should correct boundary conditions using additional Pascal triangles.